# Axios Vue.js throwing Cors error on Heroku Laravel application

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I've got a Laravel app that's hosted on Heroku, currently in  staging environment that's password protected. It's accessible via https:// but axios is making requests to http:// and causing a cors error... I've tried adding allow origin headers as middleware on the routes but that doesn't fix the error.

Is there a way to force axios to use https by default? I don't want to pass the full URL to the axios.get()

This doesn't happen on local so could it be something caused by Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Pull Request](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/pull/959) on the way that will try to access http/s if the other protocol fails. So it's a matter of time now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is actually related to Heroku but I can't be certain.

The only thing that tells me this is that I moved to an EC2 instance via Laravel Forge and I don't have any problems.

Strangely I also had a couple of files that were being requested without www. And when viewing in browser it forced the css files to the naked domain. What's weird though is other css files loaded with www. And weren't redirected so I think it could also have been a permissions thing.

I solved the file issue by simply changing the file name and the redirect stopped so maybe an overzealous redirect. Either way it was annoying and I think I tried everything so hopefully that information helps somebody else in future.

Cheers